# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index in groovy service class

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a code as per:

```
def private prepare(params) {
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource);
    String variables = params.variables

    if(variables != null && variables != "") {
        def Paths = variables.split("\\|")
        List conceptList = new ArrayList()

        Paths.each { cPath ->
            def row = sql.rows(""" SELECT firstname FROM person WHERE lastname like '${cPath}%' """).each { row ->
                conceptList.add(PersonHelperService.getLastnameFromKey(row.firstname))
            }
        }

        String[] conceptArray = conceptList.toArray()
        jobDataMap.put("c_cds", conceptArray);
    }
}
```

I do get the error while running the application:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

I have in variable Paths the list of certain paths which are already separated by function split. I am pretty sure that I am getting error while calling sql.rows. If I comment that part out along with its each function everything seems to work. But I do need that sql statement to get the list of rows which satisfies the condition.
What part of the code I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your call to rows should be

```
def row = sql.rows("SELECT firstname FROM person WHERE lastname like ${cPath + '%'}").each {
```

Comment: This saved me, but do you know why it has to be like this to work? I'm still curious. Thanks!

Comment: Groovy SQL turns the `${...}` bit into a prepared statement, so it becomes a `?` in the query. If you don't do as shown in the answer, it therefore becomes `? + '%'`. Hope this makes sense, let me know if not, I'm on my phone ATM, so hard to explain

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had a case where I had a method returning a String. When I changed it to return GString, it stopped working. My question is - is Groovy SQL not parameterizing Strings, but only GStrings, and String queries are treated like a String literal?

Answer (score 1):

Something that I experienced before is that sql.rows method have trouble with GString.

When you use string interpolation, that is not a real string, in fact it is a GString. They are mostly interchangeable, but sometimes they are not.

You can convert a GString into a regular String with the toString() method.
My suggestion for you is to re-write your query like:

```
sql.rows("SELECT firstname FROM person WHERE lastname like '${cPath}%'".toString())
```

Another, maybe cleaner, solution would be to assign the query to a String variable first.

```
String query = "SELECT firstname FROM person WHERE lastname like '${cPath}%'"
sql.rows(query).each { row -> ... }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

The below worked, thank you everyone:

```
def source= cPath+'%';
            def row = sql.rows(""" SELECT firstname FROM person WHERE lastname like 'source' """)
```

Comment: That can't have worked you have no variable expansion, also, isn't that what the two answers basically said? No up votes for either of them? No accepted answer?